# Nodejs Excel Sheet Edit & Send With Sendgrid

Tags: excel, email, cloud, nodes

I want to read an excel sheet from my cloud storage, edit specific values and then send the new excel sheet with sendgrid.

I am working with NodeJS.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the data using your HTTP client library of choice. Then parse it with the read method.

then you can manipulate the data and can write the same on cloud again.

For parsing the data you can use like this.

```
var XLSX = require('xlsx');
var workbook = XLSX.readFile('your_filename');
var sheet_name_list = workbook.SheetNames;
console.log(XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheet_name_list[0]]))
```